# ggplot geom_bar group by month and show count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm finding this surprisingly tricky. I would like to create a trended bar chart showing counts by month on a datetime filed.

Some data:

```
structure(list(id = c("p036502", "p039565", "p233823", "p185307", 
"p013780", "p063374", "p103285", "p181781", "p114989", "p191410", 
"p030093", "p226941", "p225747", "p173555", "p055350", "p060293", 
"p199435", "p074849", "p232007", "p037127", "p230221", "p116615", 
"p106275", "p070918", "p144291", "p116102", "p070029", "p107356", 
"p031939", "p044085", "p081434", "p010969", "p156550", "p048313", 
"p139731", "p048657", "p234430", "p000139", "p240738", "p047586", 
"p006436", "p211511", "p220000", "p183686", "p045806", "p246581", 
"p228935", "p176012", "p229479", "p040831", "p091593", "p151958", 
"p123997", "p017606", "p009578", "p245173", "p130035", "p207223", 
"p069404", "p186381", "p056807", "p131333", "p164867", "p250930", 
"p051288", "p183614", "p141508", "p240150", "p253358", "p055462", 
"p100203", "p216335", "p215118", "p123326", "p216043", "p190639", 
"p035608", "p194533", "p005330", "p217173", "p243195", "p204162", 
"p088899", "p218286", "p024688", "p148544", "p061723", "p062414", 
"p150704", "p064902", "p160114", "p054727", "p233164", "p164497", 
"p164688", "p226536", "p037347", "p052732", "p254241", "p041330"
), project_submitted_datetime = structure(c(1479480359, 1493222248, 
1483311464, 1471016531, 1470474551, 1478340111, 1472603443, 1470230761, 
1473806157, 1474742339, 1489079773, 1473103712, 1481203503, 1479248019, 
1486043216, 1479492186, 1473029329, 1485382089, 1461751084, 1463859966, 
1471643202, 1475223157, 1468792461, 1466087276, 1477175132, 1472419257, 
1484329230, 1476213378, 1477941424, 1477399077, 1481059184, 1483645109, 
1490904308, 1472674295, 1484011440, 1485462104, 1472038851, 1470601996, 
1487232805, 1480968888, 1484044249, 1482944283, 1488401525, 1474729990, 
1470225344, 1475788577, 1482791082, 1464016378, 1488307956, 1476242919, 
1485345902, 1487935618, 1469702976, 1488271812, 1488463835, 1481566737, 
1491245287, 1484054316, 1485724308, 1474716986, 1479078128, 1487459508, 
1463426662, 1487970888, 1470611130, 1485939126, 1462535198, 1477697562, 
1490993867, 1492697645, 1472712448, 1482328987, 1490272369, 1464291065, 
1492533451, 1469229589, 1481555129, 1470575655, 1472198934, 1476538940, 
1472054115, 1487785453, 1481195539, 1485205528, 1465419012, 1488271923, 
1471527805, 1463708265, 1466429074, 1469121081, 1474506890, 1471146637, 
1486636925, 1485953226, 1480664635, 1464224006, 1474481164, 1477663071, 
1464264088, 1484220504), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("id", 
"project_submitted_datetime"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Tried:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(aes(x = project_submitted_datetime, y = n)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

> Error: Column `y` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Tried with y = Count, y = count and similar errors.

I'm aware I could manipulate the data frame using dplyr:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(month = format(project_submitted_datetime, "%b-%Y")) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = Count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
```

But then the dates are not in order on the chart.

I wondered what options there are to achieve this? Seeking a trended bar chart, grouped by month along the horizontal axis with each bar being the count of observations in each month?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Library `zoo` has `yearmon` option to convert a date into `month-year` format. You can use that for your case.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  mutate(yrmn = as.factor(as.yearmon(project_submitted_datetime))) %>%
  group_by(yrmn) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = (yrmn), y = cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the output and I have to add text for it to work]

Without using `zoo` this is how I was able to get it.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(mn = month(project_submitted_datetime, label = TRUE),
         yr = year(project_submitted_datetime)) %>%
  group_by(yr,mn) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
  mutate(yr_mn = paste(mn, yr))

df1$yr_mn <- as_factor(df1$yr_mn)

df1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = yr_mn, y = cnt)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
```

Comment: What library do you use to get `month` function?

Answer (score 10):

Solution without changing original data.frame (only parsing date column within `ggplot2` `aes` and applying `geom_bar()` "count"):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(format(project_submitted_datetime, "%Y-%m"))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count") +
    labs(x = "Month")
```

[image]

As an alternative you can use regex: `sub("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}).*", "\\1", project_submitted_datetime)`

Comment: Thanks for this. Interesting that you specify "count" within geom_bar() but presumably I cannot within the aes itself e.g ```aes(x = blah, y = count)```?

Comment: Also, minor thing I noticed, if I change ```"%Y-%m" to  "%b-%Y"``` in order to display as month-year the ordering is lost

Comment: @DougFir I'm bookmarking this problem and look into it a little bit latter

Comment: I think I got it with this code block ```df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(project_submitted_datetime)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y", date_breaks = "1 month", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(x = "Month") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90)) # make the date labels readable```. I had to adjust the original field from a dttm class to date only

Comment: I take it back. While the x axis displays as desired I notice that the grouping by months are lost

Comment: @DougFir You can use `forcats::fct_inorder(format(x, "%b-%Y"))` to maintain ordering (assuming dates are in order to begin with).